# React Native iOS - CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for Flipper-Folly, they require a higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, react-native, flipper

When running `pod install --repo-update`, I get the following error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Flipper-Folly":


In Podfile:
    Flipper-Folly (= 2.6.0)

Specs satisfying the `Flipper-Folly (= 2.6.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I've tried changing the `use_flipper` number to `2.6` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

I found [on a forum](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2543) to change my Podfile to:

```
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.96.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '~> 2.6', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '~> 1.4' })
```

Make sure to delete your podfile.lock and then run `pod install` again.

Comment: Working for me on RN 64.3